# how does android implement the inPurgeable of BitmapFactory.Options?

Tags: android

Android has deprecated [Options.inPurgeable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPurgeable) from api 11. I know the usage and effect of inPurgeable:

> As of LOLLIPOP, this is ignored. In KITKAT and below, if this is set to true, then the resulting bitmap will allocate its pixels such that they can be purged if the system needs to reclaim memory. In that instance, when the pixels need to be accessed again (e.g. the bitmap is drawn, getPixels() is called), they will be automatically re-decoded.

but I don't know the reason of deprecation. I want to know the implementation of inPurgeable in android（implementation principle). how to re-decoded? Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298081/android-5-0-doesnt-support-bitmapfactory-options-inpurgeable). It has explain why deprecate inPurgeable. I look forward to an more deep explanation.